# Google Docs: Modify text in multiple files

Tags: google-drive, google-sheets, google-docs

I create project specifications using many individual Google Docs files. These files are seldom edited as they describe industry-specific ways of working depending on the scope of the project. I'm looking for a way to quickly edit a few key pieces of information in the header of these files, for example:

- Project Name
- Project ID
- Date Issued

My current workflow is to open each file individually and find/replace the few pieces of info needing to be changed. Ideally I would like to keep this information in a spreadsheet. When that spreadsheet is updated, it would update each of the Google Docs files. I have experimented with Linked Data but it only seems to work with tables and charts. Does anyone know of an add-in or other process to achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to [web.se]. This question isn't a good fit for this site. For one side it looks like a "primarily opinion based" but also it look as software recommendation, both type of questions are off-topic here.